# problems after UserManager.Create function call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm having some problem after calling the UserManager.Create method. The thing is that the current logged user lost his credentials after create a new user. I'll put my code here

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CrearUser(CreateUserModel model)
     {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    UserName = model.UserName,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
                    ActiveSince = Convert.ToDateTime(model.ActiveSince),
                    ActiveUntil = Convert.ToDateTime(model.ActiveUntil)
                };
                var result =  UserManager.Create(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {


                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    string code = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");


                    var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>();
                    var roleMngr = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
                    string name = roleMngr.FindById(model.rolid).Name;
                    await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, name);

                    Success(string.Format(" Usuario <b>{0}</b> Creado con Exito.", model.UserName), true);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            model.Roles = GetRoles();
            return View(model);
        }
```

**removing the code to send the confirmation mail I do not have the problem. Does anyone know what could be influencing there?**

```
string code = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id));
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
```

Comment: Let me explain a little more. This is the case in which an administrator is creating more users. The idea of the function is to create the user and redirect to the list. The problem I have is that when the administrator tries to do something else that requires administrator privileges after creating a user is redirected to the login page – Something else, it does not happen when I'm compiling, only in the production version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an error in the function to send an email and it seems that this error was affecting the session and the user was redirected to the login page. And it was happening in the development mode because the email problem was only in the production environment. Thanks bolkay for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to do *play* with the `user` object. You should get a *true* reference to the created user instead.

After checking if the user has been successfully created, you can do this:

```
if(result.succeeded)
{
  var theNewUser = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
//Do other things with the new user.
}
```

Comment: Let me explain a little more. This is the case in which an administrator is creating more users. The idea of the function is to create the user and redirect to the list. The problem I have is that when the administrator tries to do something else that requires administrator privileges after creating a user is redirected to the login page

Comment: Something else, it does not happen when I'm compiling, only in the production version. In the same way, I followed your advice I have the change that you recommended me but I am not sure it is problems with this code.